# Find max values in R

Tags: r, max

I have the problem, now you see that:

```
x<-c(1,2,3,6,4,5,6)
y=(which.max(x))
print(y)
```

*The result is **4** because it is the position of element **6** (max value). But I want the result returned is **4** and **7**.
How can I do that?

Comment: `which(x == max(x))`

Comment: because there are two elements are max.

Comment: Finding the max value in a vector is certainly *not* an `artificial-intelligence` issue - kindly do not spam irrelevant tags (removed).

Answer (score 1):

Try the below:

```
which(x==max(x))
[1] 4 7
```

If you have potential `NA` values, use

```
which(x==max(x, na.rm=T))
```

Comment: wowwww, thank you very much

Comment: please consider accepting this question then